# What is fragmentation in APC and how should I interpret it to tweak my settings?

Tags: php, caching, apc, fragmentation

What is fragmentation in APC and how should I interpret it to tweak my settings?

All in the title :) I hope.

Answer (score 0):

Read what is [Fragmentation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragmentation_%28computer%29#Data_fragmentation)
All pieces smaller than 5Mb, are considered fragmented.
Don't worry about fragmentation (in APC), take care only about size of allowed memory. By my experience, APC works more stable, when has 20%+ memory as free.